# Select an Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to select an datatype of an Array. How can I select a specific datatype of a array using JSON.stringify?

I have tried converting the datatype to a variable calling them.

```
 patogeno: TXN_COUNT[i], // converting the data to a variable
```

This is de complete code

```
var IDData = JSON.stringify([
  ["node/9837102", "node/26794", "Customer", "patongenoA", "1412451.0", 1, 520, "1412381"],
  ["node/9837102", "node/44210", "Customer", "patongenoB", "1436765.0", 2, 384, "1436693"]
]);


function createNodes(startnodes, endnodes, startnodetype, endnodetype, PayTime, TXN_COUNT, Total_Amt, SendTime) {

  var node_set = new Set();
  var links = [];
  var nodetype = d3.set();
  startnodes.forEach(function(src, i) {
    var tgt = endnodes[i];
    node_set.add({
      id: src,
      type: startnodetype[i]
    });
    node_set.add({
      id: tgt,
      type: endnodetype[i]
    });
    links.push({
      source: src,
      target: tgt,
      paytime: PayTime[i],
      patogeno: TXN_COUNT[i], // converting the data to a variable
      total_amt: Total_Amt[i],
      SendTime: SendTime[i],
      value: 1
    }); // here ---- for each >>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    /*links.forEach( (d) => if (d.patogeno == 3) {console.log("yes")}) */
  });

  startnodetype.forEach(function(src, i) {
    var tgt_type = endnodetype[i];
    nodetype.add(src);
    nodetype.add(tgt_type);
  });

  var d3GraphData = {
    nodes: [...node_set.values()].map(function(d) {
      return {
        id: d.id,
        type: d.type,
        group: 1
      }
    }),
    links: links,
    nodetype: nodetype.values().map(function(d) {
      return {
        id: d.id,
        group: 1
      }
    })
  }
  return d3GraphData;
};

function makeGraph(selector, d3GraphData) {
  var svg = d3.select(selector),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");
  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20); // color types
  var link = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(d3GraphData.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {
      return Math.sqrt(d.value);
    })
  tooltip.html("<p/>Paytime:" + d.paytime + "<p/>Patogeno:" + d.patogeno + "<p/>Amount:" + d.total_amt + "<p/>SendTime:" + d.SendTime)
})
```

I want to compare the datatype of the array and if it has a number 1 or 2, change the color of the node. I had used to call d.patogeno and show it on a mouseover with a tooltip:

```
tooltip.html("<p/>Paytime:" + d.paytime + "<p/>Patogeno:" + d.patogeno + "<p/>Amount:" + d.total_amt + "<p/>SendTime:" + d.SendTime) })
```

but when ever I try d.patogeno to use in the fill `.attr` and `if` statement it dosent work:

```
if (d.patogeno == 2) {return "red"; alert("es dos");}
```

Could anyone be so kind to give me the clue of it?
Thanks in advance.
Ignacio

Comment: you can not return and than expect the code after it to run.... It is like closing a book and continuing to read it or closing a door and continuing to walk through it.

Comment: First of all, your `makeGraph` function has an `)` too much at the end, which breaks the syntax. Second, as @epascarello says, you can not have any code after return. Switch return red, and the alert statement. If you want additional help, I suggest you include more information about why it does not work. What do you expect? What happens instead? Are there any error messages in the console?

Comment: Dear @epascarello and @KjetilNordin I thanks for your recommendations, I had load the full code at (http://www.lab-adyc.cl/test/p6.html) and comment the return the nodes appear in black and the alert doesn't appear. So the `if` statement isn't working becuase it don´t recognize the `d.patogeno`. I had switch again and now `return` all yellow. Please put the cursor in the vector it will read the `d.patogeno` and show it on a box, but it will never change color. I'm trying to change color of the node depending the value of the datatype. Could you be so kind to help me?